# Clipping using the folding library of tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{folding}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzfoldingdodecahedron[folding line length=2cm,face 1={\fill (0,0) circle (1.5cm);}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The circle in the first face is slightly too big for the pentagon. Is there a way that the circles is clipped to the pentagon? I tried using `clip` and `regular polygon` but it did not work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you really want to clip or do you want the whole polygon black?

### Path of face

Either way, the path of the face is

```
\path[
    xshift=-.5\tikz@lib@fold@length,
    yshift=-0.68819\tikz@lib@fold@length
] (0,0) -- ++ (0*72:\tikz@lib@fold@length)
        -- ++ (1*72:\tikz@lib@fold@length)
        -- ++ (2*72:\tikz@lib@fold@length)
        -- ++ (3*72:\tikz@lib@fold@length)
        -- cycle;
```

The length `\tikz@lib@fold@length` which is set by the `folding line length` key is defined in `tikzlibraryfolding.code.tex`:

```
%
% Length of a standard line in a folding
% 

\tikzoption{folding line length}{\pgfmathsetlength\tikz@lib@fold@length{#1}}
\newdimen\tikz@lib@fold@length
\tikz@lib@fold@length=2cm
```

### `\tikzfoldingpolygon[<opt arg>]`

For the sake of re-using the polygon’s path, I defined a user macro `\tikzfoldingpolygon[<opt arg>]` which takes one optional argument that is given to the polygon’s path.

```
\newcommand*{\tikzfoldingpolygon}[1][clip]{
    \path[
        folding polygon shift,
        #1
    ] (0,0) -- ++ (0*72:\tikz@lib@fold@length)
            -- ++ (1*72:\tikz@lib@fold@length)
            -- ++ (2*72:\tikz@lib@fold@length)
            -- ++ (3*72:\tikz@lib@fold@length)
            -- cycle;
}
```

#### The `folding polygon shift` style (for re-use of the shifting to the lower-left corner inside a face)

```
\tikzset{
    folding polygon shift/.style={
        xshift=-.5\tikz@lib@fold@length,
        yshift=-0.68819\tikz@lib@fold@length,
    }
}
```

#### `clip`

The default for the optional argument is `clip`, so a simple

```
\tikzfoldingpolygon
```

suffices to clip all following operations.

#### `fill`

```
\tikzfoldingpolygon[fill=green]% overwrites clip
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{folding}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    folding polygon shift/.style={
        xshift=-.5\tikz@lib@fold@length,
        yshift=-0.68819\tikz@lib@fold@length,
    }
}
\newcommand*{\tikzfoldingpolygon}[1][clip]{
        \path[
            folding polygon shift,
            #1
        ] (0,0) -- ++ (0*72:\tikz@lib@fold@length)
                -- ++ (1*72:\tikz@lib@fold@length)
                -- ++ (2*72:\tikz@lib@fold@length)
                -- ++ (3*72:\tikz@lib@fold@length)
                -- cycle;
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzfoldingdodecahedron[
    folding line length=2cm,
    face 1={% clipped
        \tikzfoldingpolygon
        \fill (0,0) circle (1.5cm);
    },
    face 2={
        \tikzfoldingpolygon[fill=green]
    },
    face 12={
        \tikzfoldingpolygon[]% empty optional argment overwrites default clip
        \fill[red] (0,0) circle (1.5cm);
    }
];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Very nice tutorial. +1

Comment: This looks very good. I'll try it, thank you!
EDIT: Tried it, worked flawlessly. Now I can make pretty pictured dodecahedrons. (Nice christmas gift)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a circle, you can use a polygon of side `5`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{folding,shapes.geometric}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzfoldingdodecahedron[folding line length=2cm,face 1={\node[draw=none,fill,regular  polygon, 
regular polygon sides=5, inner sep=.97cm,opacity=1] at (0,0) {};}];
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

But the `inner sep` has to be manually adjusted so as to fill in properly `:-(`. Also I have added the option `opacity=x`, as a personal taste (you may use it for making the thing more fancier).

Comment: The `inner sep` can be calculated by `<folding line length>/2-2\pgflinewidth`. Also, `draw=none` and `draw`?

Comment: That's not really what I wanted. I really want to clip the circle, so there are some white areas left.